# Filtering Multiple Date Ranges - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, not-exists

I am trying to exclude data from a table if a date falls within a date range.  If this was a single date then it would be a simple:

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE XYZ.DATE NOT BETWEEN DATE1 AND DATE2;
```

But for this specific requirement, I have many dates I would like to compare stored with a separate table (EXCLUDE_THESE_DATES):

```
START_DATE          END_DATE            VALUE_NAME
06-NOV-17 13:16:00  06-NOV-17 13:17:00  NAMEINQUESTION
06-NOV-17 16:34:00  17-NOV-17 16:13:00  NAMEINQUESTION
13-NOV-17 18:05:00  13-NOV-17 18:10:00  NAMEINQUESTION
13-NOV-17 20:02:00  13-NOV-17 20:03:00  NAMEINQUESTION
13-NOV-17 20:05:00  13-NOV-17 20:20:00  NAMEINQUESTION
15-NOV-17 15:14:00  15-NOV-17 15:18:00  NAMEINQUESTION
```

I was able to get all the values that fall within those dates (below) but nothing seems to get me what I'm truly looking for (dates not in those date bands).

```
SELECT
 FLD.VALUE, FLD.FILTERDATE, ETED.START_DATE, ETED.END_DATE
FROM 
  FULL_LIST_OF_DATES FLD,
  EXCLUDE_THESE_DATES ETD
WHERE FLD.VALUE_NAME = ETD.VALUE_NAME
AND FLD.VALUE_TYPE_ID = 1007
AND FLD.FILTERDATE BETWEEN '01-OCT-17 00:00:00' AND '01-APR-18 
00:00:00'
AND (FLD.FILTERDATE >= ETED.START_DATE 
AND  FLD.FILTERDATE <= ETED.END_DATE)
AND FLD.VALUE_NAME = 'NAMEINQUESTION'
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!

EDIT: 
Results based on feedback.  16:34:51 shouldn't appear because it was also in 06-NOV-17 16:34:00 to 17-NOV-17 16:13:00.

```
VALUE       FILTERDATE          START_DATE          END_DATE
480.703461  06-NOV-17 16:34:51  28-NOV-17 13:26:00  29-NOV-17 23:36:00
480.703461  06-NOV-17 16:34:51  13-NOV-17 18:05:00  13-NOV-17 18:10:00
480.703461  06-NOV-17 16:34:51  06-NOV-17 13:16:00  06-NOV-17 13:17:00
480.703461  06-NOV-17 16:34:51  13-NOV-17 20:05:00  13-NOV-17 20:20:00
480.703461  06-NOV-17 16:34:51  15-NOV-17 15:14:00  15-NOV-17 15:18:00
480.703461  06-NOV-17 16:34:51  28-NOV-17 13:10:00  28-NOV-17 13:13:00
480.703461  06-NOV-17 16:34:51  13-NOV-17 20:02:00  13-NOV-17 20:03:00
483.04837   06-NOV-17 16:35:19  28-NOV-17 13:26:00  29-NOV-17 23:36:00
483.04837   06-NOV-17 16:35:19  13-NOV-17 18:05:00  13-NOV-17 18:10:00
483.04837   06-NOV-17 16:35:19  06-NOV-17 13:16:00  06-NOV-17 13:17:00
483.04837   06-NOV-17 16:35:19  13-NOV-17 20:05:00  13-NOV-17 20:20:00
483.04837   06-NOV-17 16:35:19  15-NOV-17 15:14:00  15-NOV-17 15:18:00
483.04837   06-NOV-17 16:35:19  28-NOV-17 13:10:00  28-NOV-17 13:13:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the date comparison and an `OR` condition instead of `AND`.

Also, use the `JOIN ..ON` syntax rather than the old `a,b`

```
SELECT
 FLD.VALUE, FLD.FILTERDATE, ETED.START_DATE, ETED.END_DATE
FROM 
  FULL_LIST_OF_DATES FLD JOIN 
  EXCLUDE_THESE_DATES ETD
  ON  FLD.VALUE_NAME = ETD.VALUE_NAME
WHERE FLD.VALUE_TYPE_ID = 1007
AND FLD.FILTERDATE BETWEEN '01-OCT-17 00:00:00' AND '01-APR-18 
00:00:00'
AND ( FLD.FILTERDATE < ETED.START_DATE 
         OR  FLD.FILTERDATE > ETED.END_DATE)
AND FLD.VALUE_NAME = 'NAMEINQUESTION'
```

Comment: Yeah some old habits die hard.  I thought that was what I did before I posted and it didn't give me the results I was looking for but I'll try again :).

Comment: @GregN : It is hard to construct or test a query without knowing the records in your `FULL_LIST_OF_DATES`.Try using the `OR`  condition i mentioned in different ways if the above one does not work.

Comment: Added an edit.  It pulled in records that didn't satisfy the condition.

Comment: Well... now I see... that's because the oms_name is the same for both points and although it removed the trouble date, the other conditions are still correct and therefore they also should display.  I feel like in my head this is simplier then I'm making it.

Comment: @GregN , If you want to purely compare days, then use `TRUNC(FLD.FILTERDATE)`  . By default it compares on the time component as well.

Comment: Yeah i'm looking to compare time and days.  Right now it's a DATE format.  Should I try another one?

Comment: @GregN : You should use it only if you need it that way..But  the result `16:34:51` is expected as it is beyond end time.

Comment: Yeah it’s needed. So that record is beyond the end date but since it was already excluded by one of the other dates it should be excluded from the result as well. That’s where the rub is at.